# Presto query optimization for Kafka connector

Tags: apache-kafka, presto

I've a kafka topic with timestamp as message key and the topic is partitioned by hash of year-month. When I'm trying to query kafka using Presto, It seems that Presto will get the full set of messages. I'd like to know if the Kafka connector for Presto will do partition/offset related optimization? e.g. if I filter data by timestamp range, it'll go to the target kafka partitions without full data scan. Another use case is the ETL job which process per hour/day, could Presto intelligently locate those bunch of data e.g. proceed with last offsets?

Comment: If you search by a timestamp, it should seek to those offsets for all partitions

Comment: but Presto does not have sense of partition and seeking.

Comment: No, but it calls the kafka consumer API, which can

Comment: Are you sure? I didn't find any hint in the source code of kafka connector for Presto.

Comment: Timestamp embedded within the record will be seekable with these changes https://github.com/prestodb/presto/pull/13709

Comment: It seems that Presto will get data starting from kafka offset 0. Is it possible that Presto always get the latest data(assuming offsets are saved somewhere by Presto/Kafka)?

Comment: Presto would have to use consumer groups, at some point. I'm not sure if each query creates a random group, though